# How to read file from AWS s3 in python flask on web

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask

I want to import the s3 file and immediately show the contents of the file ('parameter.txt') on the web. 
I'm not sure which part of the code I'm putting in the file name.

This error occurs.
Please give me some advice. Thank you.

```
@app.route('/information', methods=['POST'])
def information():
    key = request.form['key']
    my_bucket = get_bucket()
    file_obj = my_bucket.Object(key).get()

    return Response(
        file_obj['Body'].read(),
        mimetype='text/plain',
        headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment:filename= 
        {}".format(key)}
      )
```

> error :...
>       return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py",
>   lin          e 634, in _make_api_call
>       api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py",
>   lin          e 682, in _convert_to_request_dict
>       api_params, operation_model)   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/validate.py",
>   l          ine 297, in serialize_to_request
>       raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
>
> botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
>   Invalid length for parameter Key, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf

Comment: I think your problem is here `key = request.form['key']`. Verify that `request.form` has the key `key`. Post an example of the value of `key`. Also exit your question to show how you are creating the boto3 client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key

keyId = "your key"
sKeyId="your_aws_secret_key_id"

srcFileName="package.json"
destFileName="package1.json"
bucketName="bucketname"
conn = boto.connect_s3(keyId,sKeyId)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketName)

#Get the Key object of the given key, in the bucket

k = Key(bucket,srcFileName)

#Get the contents of the key into a file 

k.get_contents_to_filename(destFileName)
```